# removing strings from a python list based on Hamming distance

Tags: python

I have a list

```
l = ['ATCGGG','CGGGAT,CGGGAA','ATGGCC,CTCCCT,CTCCGT,TTAAGG']
```

I want to compute the Hamming distance between strings in each element of the list and drop the strings which are less than or equal to a Hamming distance of 1 of another one. Example the expected output is

```
l = ['ATCGGG','CGGGAT','ATGGCC,CTCCCT,TTAAGG']
```

I know how to calculate the Hamming distance between two strings:

```
def hamming(s1, s2):
    if len(s1) != len(s2):
        raise ValueError("Undefined for sequences of unequal length")
    return sum(ch1 != ch2 for ch1, ch2 in zip(s1, s2))
```

I am not able to iterate correctly over the elements of the list. Please let me know of a good way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This produces exactly the output you said you wanted:

```
result = []
for group in l:
    pieces = group.split(",")
    thischunk = []
    for piece in pieces:
        if all(hamming(piece, base) > 1 for base in thischunk):
            thischunk.append(piece)
    result.append(",".join(thischunk))
print(result)
```

The output is:

```
['ATCGGG', 'CGGGAT', 'ATGGCC,CTCCCT,TTAAGG']
```